# Warning because addgroup tries to create an already existing user group

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, dpkg

I am trying to run the command `dpkg --configure -a` in order to fix dpkg so I can apt-get programs.

I get the error `addgroup: The group 'systemd-journal' already exists as a system group. Exiting.`

This apparently corresponds to the following bug.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1475094

Is there a way to overcome this problem for now to get my system working until the bug gets fixed?

The system is Ubuntu 16.04 server 32 bit.

Comment: Does the `systemd-journal` have any members? What's the output of `grep 'systemd-journal:' /etc/group`?

Comment: It appears that the group has no members,  There is no output at all.

Comment: That shouldn't be a halting error in the first place. Have you filed a bg?

Comment: There is already a bug in place.  ie the one listed above.  Should I add myself to the list of effected users or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the group is empty, you could just remove it and then run your `dpkg` command. Since the command itself, apparently, creates the group, after running it everything should be fine. So, first:

```
sudo delgroup --only-if-empty systemd-journal
```

And then

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Once that has run, make sure the group was recreated and, if not, create it again.

Comment: That solved the problem.  I had to reboot for some reason but it's working now.

Comment: You could just log off X Windows and log in again or run another shell and start virtualbox from there. New added groups does not propagate on running shell or X Windows.